# Symbian S60v3 3rd Edition FP2 SDK Emulator Unlock

Tags: symbian, s60-3rd-edition

I've been playing around with the SDKs of Symbian OS and I've encountered an issue that I couldn't bypass.

Specifically I've been using S60v3 3rd Edition Feature Pack 2 SDK's Emulator.
I want to test some .sis/.sisx application and maybe develop/fix some of them (also nostalgia from some old games that I used to play that can no longer be emulated any other way).

The issue is that all the application that I want to install on the emulator have the signature error, and since it's no longer possible to sign them I tried using one of those apps (HelloOX v2) that will remove the signature check.

Sadly those don't seem to work at all on the Emulator for some reason. Even though I checked the options in application settings to accept all software installation and disabled certificate check.

Is there a way to somehow unlock/hack the emulated OS from the SDKs? 
I know this is dead technology which makes it even harder to find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance for your help if someone actually knows.